# Visual Studio IDE error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

When i am going to run my project i am getting this error"F:\TestProjects\CallDll\CallDll\bin\Debug\CallDll.exe" is missing.Please
build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to
ponint at the correct location for the target assembly

Can any one tell me the solution

Comment: Press F7 or Ctrl+Shift+B and then F5 again?

Comment: it is not same error message coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Output Path if it points to the correct location of your executable file.

Comment: how to know OutputPath and AssemblyName properties ,,is it from property window of startup project